# Unable to retrieve cached jQuery selector in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors, angularjs-service

I am having a little trouble hiding an element. I am attempting to hide this element using an AngularJS service. My code is as follows:

```
app.service('testService', function(){
    var testElement = $("#testElement");

    this.hideElement = function(){
        testElement.hide();
    }
});
```

The code above does not actually hide the element, but the following code does:

```
app.service('testService', function(){
    this.hideElement = function(){
        var testElement = $("#testElement");
        testElement.hide();
    }
});
```

However, I have multiple functions that use the testElement and I would hate to have to keep declaring it in all the functions that need testElement within the service. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Yes. In fact your very first step was wrong. I mean having service that makes some DOM manipulations, in your case hiding HTML node. Services are data manipulation layer (retrieve, transform, save, post, etc.) but never presentation one, it should not care about View. Services are reusable piece of application code, meaning that it is supposed to be injected in different places of the app to provide a bridge to data sources, it should not make any view transformations, it's just not what they are for.

You should use directive for this with controller as mediator to decide when and what to hide and show. Most likely it will be enough to use build-in ngShow/ngHide directives with some boolean flags set in controller.

Answer (score 0):

for html manipulation better to use angular controllers or inbuilt directives. services are never recommended.
If you really want to cache something, use simple JS Constants or html5 localstorage if you cache session wise use sessionstorage, they are really helpfull. or in angular $rootscope variables are also global.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What actually happened when you assign 'testElement' outside the hide method was 'testElement' will be assigned with undefined value.Since injection are created before the dom was available.So the below code doesn't work.

```
var testElement = $("#testElement");
this.hideElement = function(){
    testElement.hide();
}
```

For DOM manipulation it is better to go with directives than services.